# need help on copy sharepoint document library file to Archive/ other document library sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have one requirement as below
while uploading document to the document library user will give expiry date for that document.
after expiry date that particular document should gets automatically moved or copied to the another document library(Archive)
I am new to sharepoint and need help on this as How I can achive this???

Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Setup a default content type for this library with a required column of End Date (or custom Expiration Date).
2. In the libary properties go to Information Management Policy Settings and select the content type that you created and assigned with the library.
3. Enable the retention policy - > Add retention stage
4. Select Field (end date or expiration date) + 1 Day
5. For the action select "Transfer for another location" (this will move).  To copy the file you might have to create a workflow.  Running a workflow is also an action option.

If you select "Transfer to another location" and receive an error telling you that no locations are specified how to resolve that can be found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-uk/sharepoint2010setup/thread/c230a42b-f2a1-4823-b280-72602981d9a1).